# Evaluate a tensor in deferred mode in Tensorflow 2

Tags: session, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to evaluate square of a tensor. 
    constant = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
    tft = constant*constant

```
#https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
with sess.as_default():
  print(tft.eval())
```

However, it returns the following error:

> NotImplementedError: eval is not supported when eager execution is
>   enabled, is .numpy() what you're looking for?

I know I can disable the eager excuation

import tensorflow as tf

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
constant = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
tft = constant*constant
print(tft)
```

But, this returns the *Tensor("mul_4:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)* and not the actual value. How can I evaluate it please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In TF 2.x, you can evaluate tensor with in the session is as below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  constant = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
  tft = constant*constant
  print(tft.eval())
```

Output:

```
2.2.0
[1 4 9]
```

There is another method without session you achieve this by converting `tensor` to `numpy` to see actual value

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(tf.__version__)

def tensor_to_array(array_value):
    return array_value.numpy()

constant = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
tft = constant*constant

print(tft)
print(tensor_to_array(tft))
```

Output:

```
2.2.0
tf.Tensor([1 4 9], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
[1 4 9]
```

Comment: `tft.numpy()` works  well when migrating  old code with `eval`